# is JAXB a specification or an implementation?

Tags: java, jaxb, implementation, specifications

If it is a specification, how can I get a comprehensive list of implementations that conform to this specification?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JAXB itself is a specification.

Sun provides a Reference Implementation for it, which is now maintained under GlassFish.
JaxMe is another implementation of the JAXB specification maintained by Apache.

The Eclipse Foundation also maintains another implementation, MOXy, under EclipseLink.

Answer (score 10):

JAXB is both!

- [JSR 222](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222), the specification.
- [Project JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/), the [reference implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_implementation).